# Style and Efficiency question related to adding a column calculate from a combination of rows to a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements, series

This is a question regarding style and code efficiency.  I am trying to add a data column to a pandas dataframe that is calculated based on the values in other columns in the row.

I have used this approach and it works well and although I don't know for sure, it looks clean and efficient when there is only one conditional element per condition.

```
conditions=[(s1['Price'] <= s1['Bid']),(s1['Price'] > s1['Bid'])]
values=['Sale','Purchase']
s1['Trans_Type'] = np.select(conditions,values)
```

When I try to do this with two conditions such as:

```
conditions =[((s1['Type'] == 'C') and (s1['Trans_Type'] =='Purchase')),((s1['Type'] == 'C') and (s1['Trans_Type'] =='Sale'))]
```

I get an error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Which I understand has to do with the fact that two series are being compared and not just row element by row element.  I really don't understand this, and any insights into what would needs to be changed to get this to work would be appreciated.

I can solve the issue by doing the following, but I'm thinking there really has to be a cleaner solution than this... I guess you could say it looks a bit 'iffy' to me and I expect it is inefficient.

```
def hedge_handler(row):   
    if (row['Type']=='C'):
        if (row['Trans_Type'] == 'Purchase'): 
            factor=1
        else:
            factor =-1
    else:
        if (row['Trans_Type'] == 'Purchase'):
            factor=-1
        else:
            factor = 1    
    return factor

s1['Hedge_Shares']=s1.apply(hedge_handler,axis=1) *  s1['Hedge_Shares']         
s1
```

Any insight into better approaches would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: a specific programming problem, or    -   check
a software algorithm, or   -  check
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is  -  check
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development   - check
…then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the only thing needed to fix the first option is to use **&** instead of **and**

```
conditions =[((s1['Type'] == 'C') & (s1['Trans_Type'] =='Purchase')),((s1['Type'] == 'C') & (s1['Trans_Type'] =='Sale'))]
```

works ... not sure why.